# Why is a semi-colon instead of an empty block not always valid?

Tags: c#, syntax

I've been wondering this for a while now; why is it that using a semi-colon `;` instead of an empty block `{}` is not always valid? It works when using it on statements like `while`, `for`, `if`, `else` etc. But it does not work for `try`, `catch`, `finally` and `delegate` (probably a less useful to leave empty).

So doing something like this would be valid:

```
while(shouldIWait()); // This is normal

try {
    doThing(); // Might throw an exception
} catch { } // Ignore the exception
```

But this would not:

```
try {
    doThing(); // Might throw an exception
} catch; // Syntax error!
```

From my understanding a semi-colon can always be used instead of an empty block. Why is this limited to certain statements? Is there a real difference between the usage of `{ }` and `;` behind statements?

Comment: You also cannot use semi-colon for an empty method body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Try-Catch require curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999422/why-does-try-catch-require-curly-braces)

Comment: @Dennis_E That question is more of a logic flow question. Just like doing this: `if(foo) if(bar) baz(); else bor(); else beer();`

Comment: Designers possibly just want you to do it their way (which talks about try -blocks and catch-blocks). Their reasoning for forcing you to do this might be just to increase the readability of your code.

Comment: It also says why you **must** use braces with try-catch. It is to prevent ambiguities.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms The thing is that it's not just C# that does this. I've experienced the same thing in Java. I'm mostly wondering if there is a special reason for this. If there is a real difference between just doing `;` and `{ }`.

Comment: What do you mean by difference ? If both were allowed there would be no difference between the 2 of them. But for an eventually non technical/logical reason some people decided to not allow one in the context of an catch-block. So the only difference is you can use one and not use the other. I doubt that it has a deeper meaning. Of course this is just speculation at this point.

Comment: It is required by the C# Specification. See chapter 8, _Statements_. Specifically, the `if` statement (section 8.7.1) contains an _embedded-statement_ while a `try` statement (section 8.10) contains a _block_. An _embedded-statement_ can be any of a number of things, only one of which is a _block_ (8.2). Another is an _empty-statement_ (8.3). See the beginning of Chapter 8 for these definitions.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen, After reading chapters 8.7.1, 8.8(partially) and 8.10 the reasoning behind it becomes much clearer. The C# specification on it's own seems like a great read to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JeppeStigNielsen explained:

> It is required by the C# Specification. See chapter 8, Statements. Specifically, the `if` statement (section 8.7.1) contains an embedded-statement while a `try` statement (section 8.10) contains a block. An embedded-statement can be any of a number of things, only one of which is a block (8.2). Another is an empty-statement (8.3). See the beginning of Chapter 8 for these definitions.

From what I can understand from[the documentation is that statements like `if`, `while` etc. Expect any type of embedded-statement. These are things such as blocks `{ }`, empty statements `;`, etc. The `try` statement requires a block and not just any embedded statement (See beginning of chapter 8).

The documentation can either be downloaded [directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) or be found on your local hard drive `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\` (via @JeppeStigNielsen).

Comment: Note that the specification is also on your local computer if you have Visual Studio. It is in a folder typically called ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\`` (the 12.0 corresponds to VS2013).

Answer (score 2):

In some case a block of code is optional, in some case it is required.

In case of a method of a class or struct, a block of code is required (unless it is an abstract or partial method).

In case of a catch, a block of code (to handle the exception) is also required. Creating an empty catch-block is considered bad programming.

Comment: Technically (from the C# Language Specification section 10.6) a _method-body_ can be either a _block_ or just a `;`. The `;` used for a method body by abstract methods, interface methods, `extern` methods, etc. is not an _empty-statement_. The same with _accessor-body_ from a property, for example an auto-property.